# Add bibliography to my beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, presentations

I would like to add my bibliography to my presentation in IEEE format. What should I add to my preamble and code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number] 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\section{Reference}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Reference}

\end{frame}
```

I'm using the same bibTex which I use to make the IEEE paper.

Comment: There is no real difference to an article or a memoir document, so have a look at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber

Comment: i added the following code to my beamer but its of no use
`\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\section{Reference}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Reference}
\addbibresource{example.bib}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}`

Comment: I guess `\addbibresource` has to be in the preamble?

Comment: It not getting printed but rather I'm getting an error message.

Comment: Please add a minimal working example to the question. Almost every question should contain one.

Comment: Also, which error? Cannot read your mind or look over your shoulder.

Comment: `\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}`. The rest would be the same as in https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber#A_bibliography_in_a_presentation

Comment: Off-topic: you don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}` with beamer

Answer (score 12):

From your comments it seems as if you are using `biblatex`.

Adding a bibliogrpahy to beamer works as in any other documentclass. The main points are that you have to cite some works in the text, otherwise the bibliography will be empty and that `\addbibresource{WhatEverName.bib}` should be used in the preamble.

The default `IEEE` style is numeric, which is a bit tricky, as beamer normally does not show the numbers in the bibliography. However they can be enables with `\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{knuth,
  author       = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  title        = {The {\TeX} book},
  date         = 1984,
  maintitle    = {Computers \& Typesetting},
  volume       = {A},
  publisher    = {Addison-Wesley},
  location     = {Reading, Mass.},
  langid       = {english},
  langidopts   = {variant=american},
  sortyear     = {1984-1},
  sorttitle    = {Computers & Typesetting A},
  indexsorttitle= {The TeXbook},
  indextitle   = {\protect\TeX book, The},
  shorttitle   = {\TeX book}
}

@article{einstein,
    author = {Einstein, A.},
    title = {Die Grundlage der allgemeinen Relativitätstheorie},
    journal = {Annalen der Physik},
    volume = {354},
    number = {7},
    doi = {10.1002/andp.19163540702},
    pages = {769--822},
    year = {1916}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \cite{einstein} \cite{knuth}
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{bibliography}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]