# Weird symbol when combining biblatex with beamerposter

Tags: beamer, biblatex, beamerposter

When combining biblatex with beamerposter, I get a weird symbol in place of the bibliography reference counter. Here's the minimum code I used to reproduce my issue.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=a1,scale=1.4]{beamerposter}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage[backend=biber, maxbibnames=2, maxcitenames=2, sortcites=true, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\small}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{dr1957cat,
title={The Cat in the Hat},
author={Seuss, Dr. and Ginsburg, Avi},
series={Beginner books},
year={1957},
publisher={Random House}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usetheme{default}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[label={sec:org1b2094c}]{}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.9\columnwidth}
\begin{block}{Introduction}
Fusce sagittis, libero non molestie mollis, magna orci ultrices dolor, at vulputate neque nulla lacinia eros. Aliquam erat volutpat.  Nunc eleifend leo vitae magna. \cite{dr1957cat}  In id erat non orci commodo lobortis.  Proin neque massa, cursus ut, gravida ut, lobortis eget, lacus.
\end{block}

\begin{block}{References}
\printbibliography
\end{block}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here's a picture of the problem, note the small "paper" symbol instead of the reference counter:

[image]

For completeness, I tried compiling the document with both pdflatex and xelatex using the following commands:

```
latexmk -pdflatex='pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode' -pdf -bibtex -f %f"
```

and

```
latexmk -pdflatex='xelatex -interaction nonstopmode' -pdf -bibtex -f %f"
```

Texlive 2016 on a CentOS machine.

Has anyone seen this before? What can I do to fix this?
Thank you.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68080/35864

Comment: If you want want to show the reference counter, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/419506/36296 but I don't think this makes sense without a numeric style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't like this cute little symbol, you can disable it with `\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}`

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=a1,scale=1.4]{beamerposter}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage[backend=biber, maxbibnames=2, maxcitenames=2, sortcites=true, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\small}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{dr1957cat,
title={The Cat in the Hat},
author={Seuss, Dr. and Ginsburg, Avi},
series={Beginner books},
year={1957},
publisher={Random House}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usetheme{default}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}


\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}
%\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}% for numeric bib styles

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[label={sec:org1b2094c}]{}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.9\columnwidth}
\begin{block}{Introduction}
Fusce sagittis, libero non molestie mollis, magna orci ultrices dolor, at vulputate neque nulla lacinia eros. Aliquam erat volutpat.  Nunc eleifend leo vitae magna. \cite{dr1957cat}  In id erat non orci commodo lobortis.  Proin neque massa, cursus ut, gravida ut, lobortis eget, lacus.
\end{block}

\begin{block}{References}
\printbibliography
\end{block}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's cute, but unexpected. I thought I had problems with my fonts. In any case, thank you for your answer.

Comment: @dangom You don't use beamer often enough if it is enexpected :)

Comment: No, it's indeed the first time.

Comment: Would `\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}` not be safer in case one decides to use a numeric style? Or is there something more to it?

Comment: @moewe On the other hand it might be confusing to see `\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}` in the code and nothing is displayed for authoryear style.

Comment: @moewe I added the alternative solution as comment

Comment: Thank you. I'm wondering if `\insertbiblabel` should be the go-to option for all styles or if there could be negative consequences of using it instead of `\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}`?

Comment: @moewe It seems to work fine with the normal styles shipped with biblatex. The problem is the infinity of custom styles out there - I'm sure one of them will break it :)

Comment: @moewe My personal opinion: This should be set in the bibliography style.

Comment: I had a look at the beamer code and I think `\insertbiblabel` should be fine. But I don't think I can agree that bibliography styles should set the correct `\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}`. My reasons are of course `biblatex`-centric but I believe that style authors should not have to worry about modifications applied by document classes.

Comment: @moewe I can agree to disagree :) Beamer uses the little icons. If a style wants to display something else, the style should make the modification.

Comment: Mhhh, but what would you say if the author of the KOMA classes were to change his classes in a way that would always typeset the bibliography entries in pink font over the picture of a beautiful unicorn by default and would offer an interface `\KOMAoptions{nounicornbib=true}` to turn that off? Would it then be up to style authors to set that option if they don't like unicorns? The lines get blurred once a class or package interferes with the workings of another package.

Comment: @moewe I'd sent him my pink unicorn duck to use as an image :) Back to serious: The only real problem I see are numeric styles and the ones of the form `ABC96`. For authoryear I think the icons are a gain in information.

Comment: @moewe IMHO bibliographies in presentation should serve a different purpose than bibs in written documents. In written documents, it most of the time a place to look up more detailed informations about the cited works. In a presentation this does not really work. A number on a slide is more or less useless as it is forgotten when the speaker finally shows the references at the end of the talk. I think a bibliography in a talk makes sense for example for "further reading", where it is nice to distinguish the different types by icon.

Comment: @moewe There is also a predefined template `\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]` that inserts the bib label.